# Oracle ServiceStack.OrmLite Sqlxpression creates

Tags: oracle, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Given the following definitions:

```
[Alias("USERS")]
public partial class USER : IHasId<string> 
{
    [Alias("USER_ID")]
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public string USERNAME { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public string PASSWORD { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public decimal ACTIVESTATUS { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public DateTime CREATIONDATE { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public DateTime LASTMODIFIEDDATE { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public DateTime ACTIVATEDATE { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public DateTime DEACTIVATEDATE { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public decimal ISACTIVEDIRECTORY { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public string CLIENTIDS { get; set;}
}

[Alias("USERPROFILES")]
public partial class USERPROFILE : IHasId<decimal> 
{
    [Alias("USERPROFILEID")]
    [Required]
    public decimal Id { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public decimal PROFILEID { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public string USER_ID { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public decimal ISPRIMARY { get; set;}
}


[Fact]
public void CanQueryUserSecurity()
{
    string connection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyConnKey"];
    using (IDbConnection db = connection.OpenDbConnection())
    {

        var result = db.Select<USER>(q =>
            q.LeftJoin<USER, USERPROFILE>((user, profile) => user.Id == profile.USER_ID)
            .Where<USER>(user => user.USERNAME == "sangee.ram")
            .Where<USERPROFILE>(profile => Sql.In(profile.PROFILEID, new[] { 1, 441, 442, 452 }))
            .Limit(skip: 1, rows: 2));

        Assert.NotNull(result);

    }
}
```

Results in this exception being thrown.

```
DEBUG: SELECT * FROM (
SELECT "_ss_ormlite_1_".*, ROWNUM RNUM FROM (
SELECT USERS.USER_ID AS Id, USERS.USERNAME, USERS."PASSWORD", USERS.ACTIVESTATUS, USERS.CREATIONDATE, USERS.LASTMODIFIEDDATE, USERS.ACTIVATEDATE, USERS.DEACTIVATEDATE, USERS.ISACTIVEDIRECTORY, USERS.CLIENTIDS 
FROM USERS LEFT JOIN USERPROFILES  ON (USERS.USER_ID = USERPROFILES.USER_ID)
WHERE (USERS.USERNAME = 'sangee.ram') AND USERPROFILES.PROFILEID In (1,441,442,452) ORDER BY USER_ID) "_ss_ormlite_1_"
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1 + 2) "_ss_ormlite_2_" WHERE "_ss_ormlite_2_".RNUM > 1

Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleExceptionORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, Boolean bCheck)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteResultsFilterExtensions.ExprConvertToList(IDbCommand dbCmd, String sql)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteExecFilter.Exec(IDbConnection dbConn, Func`2 filter)
   at LO.Leads.UI.Tests.UserSecurityTests.CanQueryUserSecurity() in UserSecurityTests.cs: line 35
```

It looks like the 'ORDER BY USER_ID' needs to be aliased, and I don't know enough about the SqlExpression class to modify it.

**update**

if I take the gen'd sql statement and alias 'ORDER BY **USERS.USER_ID**' correctly, the statement executes

Thank you,
Stephen

Comment: this problem means that there are two tables involved and you are bringing two fields with same name or alias. At first look I could find: `[Alias("USER_ID")] [Required] public string Id { get; set;}` for class USER and `[Required] public string USER_ID { get; set;}` fro class USERPROFILE. If this is your error I will add it as an answer.